# Getting the intensity of each colour in a captured image in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, photos

In my app, I am capturing an image and want to get the intensity of each colour. Which way is the best way to proceed?

Comment: you have to show what did you try at first ? are trying to apply filter to the image?

Comment: do you mean intensity or density? Intensity of a color is a bit of a vague term. But if you mean the density (how much of each color there is in a certain image) then this is not as hard as it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read on this article about Pixel Manipulation in swift.

https://medium.com/hacking-ios/uiimage-pixel-play-extension-in-swift-7c6fe90396b6

Once you are done with it. A good strategy for collecting color data from an image is to loop through each of its pixels and store each pixel's color information in an array and then loop through them to derive the insight you want from that data.